# .NETCore 3.1 override custom value in docker compose

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I'm working on .net core 3.1 service worker. I've create a docker template and I'm able to create and start my container. So now I need to create 2 copy of same service 1 on port 1111 and second to port 2222.

My appsettings.json has a variabile

```json
{
....
  Service : 
  {
   Port: "1111"
  }
```

If I start the first container I read from appsettings.json and port is set to 1111 so now I need to override port. I create a compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  broker:
    environment:
          SERVICE__PORT: 9999
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}service1
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: service1\Dockerfile
    volumes: 
      - ./Settings/appsettings.docker.json:c:/app/appsettings.json
      - ./Logs:c:/app/logs
```

But no varibile override. I add the

```
FROM  mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1

WORKDIR /app
ENV SERVICE__PORT=1234

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "service1.dll"]
```

If I debug my code I see a lot off provider and on EviromentSet I see my var.
On CreateHostBuilder I add some part to add loggin

```cs
            host.ConfigureLogging(
                loggingBuilder =>
                {
                    loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
                    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                        .Build();
                    var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration);


                    var logger = loggerConfig.CreateLogger();
                    loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(logger, dispose: true);
                }
            );
```

And when my service start I try to get value via configuration service

```cs
 public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

...
 private async Task StartServer()
        {
            
            try
            {

....
                var port = _configuration["Service:Port"] == ""
                    ? 9876
                    : Convert.ToInt32(_configuration["Service:Port"]);
....
}
```

I also try to mount volume via compose but not work if I run docker comand via -v switch but from VS2019 not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to support overriding of appsettings with environment variables you have to enable the environment variable support when you create the host builder.

```cs
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                        .Build();
```

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: It works! I've a second issue beacuse on main I add JsonProvider but after remove that and add Env variables all work fine. Thanks